# Donkey kick primary muscle used

Tags: muscle, exercise-technique

I know that in donkey kicks, glutes are the major muscle used. However I would like to ask about a technical aspect of this exercise, if while rising, the knee is kept  bent (the angle  alpha  in the picture) with an angle less than  90°, does this will be trageting more the glute muscles? 
Or in general what  is  the  obatined effect on  the muscles if the knee is kept highly bending in donkey kicks?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bending your knee keeps the weight of your leg closer to your center of mass.  Put simply the exercise is easier but your ROM is decreased.

---

That being said there are much better exercise selections.  Even just a basic sit to stand *(a squat)* is a much more challenging and functional exercise.

---

A more technical answer - the greater the degree of flexion, the more your Rectus Femoris (which crosses your hip and knee joint) limits your range of motion (ROM).

[image]

Comment: Yes it does.  Please post your answer or explain what you're talking about.

Comment: Apologies. I reread the answer and the question, and I got off track on what OP was asking.

Comment: Not a big deal -- read it a few times myself thought I was missing something lol